# Octave: transparent surfaces, how?

Tags: gnuplot, octave

I try to plot transparent surfaces in Octave using facealpha set to 0.2.
Ok, I have read that this is not implemented, but if I run this code, I get
a plot with a transparent plane.

`

```
close all;
clf reset;
cla reset;
graphics_toolkit("gnuplot");
colormap(bone(64));
a1=-1;b=1;h1=0.01;# making a mesh
x2=a1:h1:b;
nz2=length(x2);
[X1,Y1]=meshgrid(x2,x2);
Z1=zeros(nz2,nz2); # function equal to zero on the mesh
s1=mesh(X1,Y1,Z1);
 view([120 40]);
# properties of the faces and edges 
set(s1,'edgecolor','none')
set(s1,'facecolor','black')`
set(s1,'facealpha',0.05)
hold on
scatter3([-0.5 0],[-0.5 0],[0.5 -0.5],8,'k','.');# two points one above               # and one below the plane
 # print to eps
 print -deps testsurface.eps
```

`

this figure pops up and if I save it the plane remains transparent: [image]

but if I look at the printed version with the print command, I get
this with a non-transparent plane, one point is now invisible:
[image]
Is it possible to get the transparent plane with the print command or do I have always to save the pop-up plot window?

I am Edit:running Octave 4.02 on Xubuntu 16.04.

**EDIT:** If I try it with *fltk*, same result, with *qt* the plane vanishes.

Comment: what graphics_toolkit are you using? have you tried switching to a different graphics_toolkit (qt, fltk, gnuplot)

Comment: @Nick J, in my code is written in line four *graphics_toolkit("gnuplot");*. And I tried the others.

Comment: Sorry, missed that.